# Wordpress site performance related

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I replaced the home page with static html page with links to the posts in my site. In one section of the site I am loading recent 10 posts. For this I am using a notepad file, where I am storing the recent 10 posts links( In order to minimize database queries )

Will there be any advantage in calling the data from the notepad file, instead of a database query.

Please suggest me some tips to enhance the performance of my site.

Comment: What do you mean by `notepad` file? a simple text file?

Comment: yes... exactly... thru iframe I am showing the content

Comment: Another HTTP request to load a separate page via. an iframe will be much slower (for the user) than one simple database query to get the latest posts.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress sites can quickly become pretty slow, especially if you're using a lot of plugins etc.. Fixing this by manually creating static pages seems a bit shortsighted to me, since you're basically throwing the main reason for using a CMS–like system out the window.

It sounds to me like **caching** should solve your problems just fine. Install and configure e.g. a plugin like [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) and you server will automatically create, update and serve static HTML for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPSupercache + Cloudflare , All your traffic will be routed through the CloudFlare system, and you'll enjoy all this features and more for free :
- Cache all your static content automatically (FREE CDN).
- They protect your web site.
- Website preloader.
- (JS - CSS - HTML) Files compression.